# When adding bottomNavigationBar - all widgets disappear. Why?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my question - ***when adding a bottomNavigationBar, all other widgets on the main page disappear. What is the problem?***

If you remove the footer, then everything will work fine. There are no errors in the console, so I don't understand what could be the problem. Can you help me?
Here is the footer code -

https://dpaste.org/DW1PY#L21
And here's how I render the footer -

```
 bottomNavigationBar: const Footer()
```

I don’t know, maybe you need more information, if so, please specify in the comments - which one and I will edit my question

PS: I did not add the code here, because I don’t know what exactly you need from the footer, and there are a little more than 100 lines

Comment: I couldn't find Footer widget in flutter/material.dart library. From where do you have this widget? Can you link a package or if it is your own - show its code?

Comment: ofc - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html